# Есть ли инструмент для отслеживания запросов к БД от приложения?

Tags: c#, oracle, аудит

Есть БД Oracle. Есть приложение, которое делает запросы к этой БД.

Есть ли профилировщик, отладчик, или другой инструмент, который позволяет видеть запросы, которые делает приложение?

Comment: Да, в Oracle [предусмотрен аудит](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28337/tdpsg_auditing.htm) и можно отслеживать различную информацию. Лично я использую для данных целей `toad`, другие варианты не пробовал.

Comment: [Oracle: is there a tool to trace queries, like Profiler for sql server?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/148648/312041)

Comment: [ASH Viewer](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ashv/) - лучшее, что я видел. Еще есть Oracle OEM, но он чересчур монструозен, на мой вкус. Хотя мощная вещь, ничего не скажешь. Ну и отдельные пакеты, вьюхи и прочие тулы в разных IDE, но там уже больше руками делать надо.

Answer (score 2):

Какой-то особый инструмент не обязателен. Посмотреть, какие запросы послало приложение в БД,  можно  простым [запросом в общей области SQL](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/V-SQL.html#GUID-2B9340D7-4AA8-4894-94C0-D5990F67BE75) (все инструменты сообственно и делают этот запрос). Замените в запросе имя и пользователя приложения:

```sql
set lines 9999 pages 999 long 200000
col module for a16
col sql_fulltext for a60 wrap
select sql_fulltext, module, executions, last_active_time     
from v$sql 
where parsing_user_id = (
    select user_id from ALL_USERS where USERNAME = user)
                         --пользователь приложения--^ 
and module = 'SQL*Plus'
--имя приложения--^ 
order by last_active_time desc;
```

Пример вывода:

```
SQL_FULLTEXT                                                 MODULE           EXECUTIONS LAST_
------------------------------------------------------------ ---------------- ---------- -----
select e.employee_id, e.last_name, department_name           SQL*Plus                  2 15:17
from hr.employees e
join hr.departments d on d.department_id = e.department_id
where e.department_id = 10
```